# I want create checbkox with each.store

Tags: extjs, checkbox, each

I have store from json: 
   var store = gridQuestion.getStore();

where json--> data: [{id:1, value1:a},{id:2, value1:b}…]

and i want create dynamically checkbox.

```
var valores1 = [];


                  store.each(function(records){

                    valores1=records.data.get('value1');
```

### });

```
var grid = 
        url: getRelativeURI('uu/yy/grid.do'),
        height: 170,
        page: 6
    });
```

Ajax.requestJsonData({
            url: getRelativeURI('/uu/yy/grid.do'),
            method: 'GET',
            scope: this,
            params: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function(records) {
                var store = grid.getStore();

```
            var adm= new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < records.total; i++) {


                store.insert(i, aux);
                adm[i] = records.data[i].description;
                var idQuestion = records.data[i].id;



                Ext.each(adm, function(admdatos) {
                    adm.push({id: admdatos, text: admdatos});
                });

                 var options = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 44,
                    style: 'margin: 95px 15px 15px 155px;',
                    items: [adm]
                });
```

I have a problem!!!!

Comment: That's `records.get('value1')` or `records.data.value1`, not both. You should express what is your problem and actually ask a question.

Comment: the problem is that, records.get('value1') and recodrs.data.value1 in firebug is empty.

Comment: What does your store's Model look like?

Comment: Here is my code. For create buttons with each.